# How to display only some posts of a term of a taxonomy?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to display only some posts of a taxonomy.
So I make a $args array but I don't know how to get only the terms of the taxonomy.

Also, I don't know how to display only the posts of the term I want.

I made this but it didn't work, maybe it can help you :

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'offres_emploi',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'metiers',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => 1
        )
    ),
    'caller_get_posts' => 1,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
);

$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
$my_query->query('showposts=5&terms==1');
if ($my_query->have_posts()) {
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : echo $my_query->the_post(); ?>
```

I certainly made some mistakes.
Can you help me? TY.

Comment: You have field id but you put a slug

Comment: So what I need to do in my code?

Comment: can you tell me what terms you need to display just for sample two or three? either ID or name or something.

Comment: I want to display only the posts which have the term "Ingénieur DevOps" of my taxonomy "metiers". By the way, I don't know how to get the ID of a term, maybe you can enlighten me on it. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this instead.  IF in fact your slug is 'metiers'

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'offres_emploi',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'metiers',
            'field' => 'slug', // Select taxonomy term by. Possible values are ‘term_id’, ‘name’, ‘slug’ or ‘term_taxonomy_id’. Default value is ‘term_id’.
            'terms' => 1
        )
    ),
    'caller_get_posts' => 1,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
);
```

You can find the taxonomy terms on this page https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters

You can also hover on the term in the categories list, and see the term ID in the link.  Or click on the term, and find the "TERM ID" in the URL.